# MacOs shell know the ports where node

Tags: node.js, macos, shell, terminal, port

It would be possible to know the ports on which a program using node is running.

I currently use this, but it also finds me ports that don't use node.

```
netstat -Watnlv |
grep LISTEN |
awk '{"ps -ww -o args= -p " $9 | getline procname; print $4 }' |
grep '[*]' | sort -u | sed "s/*.//"
```

Comment: Worth noting [`lsof` does a great job of this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26887/lsof-and-listening-ports) without `grep` and `awk` involved.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single node server and program `pgrep`, this should give you the port number :

```
netstat -Watnlv | awk -v pid=$(pgrep node) '$1 ~ "tcp4" && $6 == "LISTEN" && $9 == pid{sub(".*\\.","",$4);print $4}'
```

Try this :

```
for pid in $(pgrep node); do
    netstat -Watnlv | awk -v pid=$pid '$1 ~ "tcp4" && $6 == "LISTEN" && $9 == pid{sub(".*\\.","",$4);print "node process " pid " has port " $4}'
done
```

Is this one-liner what you expected ?

```
for pid in $(pgrep node); do netstat -Watnlv | awk -v pid=$pid '$1 ~ "tcp4" && $6 == "LISTEN" && $9 == pid{sub(".*\\.","",$4);print "node process " pid " has port " $4}'; done
```

Comment: Error: `awk: can't open file 3401
 source line number 1`

Comment: `awk is /usr/bin/awk`

Comment: Ah, `pgrep node` must have given more than 1 process ID. Can you post the result of `ps -ef|grep -w node` ?

Comment: If I have three node ports open the first one doesn't work, if I take from the second only the part inside the do... done, it only gives me the last port that was requested in execution order. Since I have to run it in one line, is there a way to do it without using the loop? https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDUFz.png